# Stuck with script that uses AJAX GET to add json data to my table

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, dom

Hello and thanks in advance for reading! I have in my HTML a form element in which you can fill in 5 bars of data. This data is send with my api key to a database. The database then contains an array of this input E.G.: {"brand": "brand", "screensize": 5, "image": "image", "model": "model", "os": "os", "id": 8636}. Now i need to get this input back from the database and make it fill in a table dynamically. TL;dr I have a form element with 5 input bars, when i click submit i need to get the text in the bars to appear in my table. Here is what i tried:

```
<td>
    <input onclick="myFunction()" type="submit" value="submit">
</td>

<script>

function myFunction() {

var api = 'https://wt.ops.labs.vu.nl/api18/xxxxxxxx';

$(document).ready(function(){

jQuery.support.cors = true;

$.ajax(
{
type: "GET",
url: 'https://wt.ops.labs.vu.nl/api18/xxxxxxxx',
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
cache: false,
success: function (data) {

    var trHTML = '';                
    $.each(data.products, function (i, item) {            
    trHTML += '<tr><td>' + data.products[i].brand + '</td><td>' +  
         data.products[i].os + '</td><td>' + data.products[i].model 
         + '</td><td>' + data.products[i].image + '</td><td>' + 
         data.products[i].screensize + '</td></tr>';
    });        
     $('#products').append(trHTML);

    },

error: function (msg) {            
alert(msg.responseText);
}
});
})
}   

</script>
```

Note; i replaced api key with xxxxxxxx and products is my table id

When i click submit with this script, it sends me to the API URL and doesnt append anything to the html. I need to stay on the current page and append the form elements to the table when I hit submit.

Comment: `type="submit"` - you are submitting a form ... you need to prevent the default action of a form submit - try `onclick="myFunction(); return false;"` - though I don't know if that will actually help ... best bet is, if you don't want to submit a form, don't use a form in the first place

Comment: Thanks for your respone! I tried this but im still stuck.

Comment: what have you changed?

Comment: I tried to use onsubmit="return myFunction()" according following this link: https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_validation_js

Comment: does your function `return false` - if not, then add that

Comment: Thanks again! If I call the line return false; on the end of my function the submit button indeed doesn't return anything, but it also prohibits it from submitting data and neither do i get an append

Comment: You're missing the `data:` option to `$.ajax`, so you're not sending any parameters to the API. There's also no point in using `contentType:` with `GET` requests, since they don't send any content.

Comment: You don't need to use `$(document).ready()` inside a function that's called from a submit handler.

Answer (score 0):

The function needs to send the inputs from the form. You can use the jQuery `.serialize()` method to do this.

Change the submit button to send the event to the function:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="myFunction(event)">
```

Then you can use this in the function to prevent the default submission and also find the corresponding form to serialize.

```
function myFunction(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var button = event.target;
    var api = 'https://wt.ops.labs.vu.nl/api18/xxxxxxxx';

    jQuery.support.cors = true;

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: api,
        data: $(button.form).serialize(),
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            var trHTML = '';                
            $.each(data.products, function (i, item) {            
                trHTML += '<tr><td>' + data.products[i].brand + '</td><td>' +  
                    data.products[i].os + '</td><td>' + data.products[i].model 
                    + '</td><td>' + data.products[i].image + '</td><td>' + 
                    data.products[i].screensize + '</td></tr>';
            });        
            $('#products').append(trHTML);
        },
        error: function (msg) {            
            alert(msg.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, unfortunately the event.preventDefault(); doesn't work, it still sends me to the page of the api link. Furthermore, nothing is added in the table

Comment: Why don't you just make it not a submit button, i.e. `<input type="button">`?

Comment: Are you sure the function is being called? Are there any errors in the console?